# Why is this vulnerable to NullPointerException?

Tags: java, exception

```
private static final Parser parser = getParser();

private static Parser getParser() {
        try {
             if (useParser) {
                return GenericParser.getParser();
              }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return null;
    }  

  public ParsedSentence parse(String sentence){
       if (sentence==null) {
           throw new IllegalArgumentException("sentence can't be null");
       }

         return new ParsedSentence(parser.parse(sentence));
    }
```

IDE reports that "parse" method may produce a null pointer exception. If sentence is null, how can it gets to the place of the parse() method? because the exception is thrown and the program terminates. Right?

If it is indeed possible to get a null, does that mean the return value of this method could be null as well?

Edited again: OK. Now I can present a more complete example to illustrate the picture. Yes, parser could be null, but if it's null, another exception would have been already thrown in the getParser() method. In this case, why does the parser.parse(sentence) method have the chance to receive a null pointer exception?

Comment: Where is `parser` initialized? That would be the possible null reference in this snippet.

Comment: parser is initialized in a static block in this class.

Comment: A valid [mcve] (MCVE) would help clarify all confusion

Comment: My question can be as simple as "once an exception is shown, does the logic terminates immediately after the exception, or is it possible to continue, depending on the context"?

Comment: No, the method does not continue after throwing an exception.  That’s why everyone is telling you that `parser` is probably the cause, rather than `sentence`.

Comment: @VGR, so parser could be a null pointer?

Comment: _"another exception would have been already thrown in the getParser() method"_ Yes it would be thrown, but you swallow it and return `null`, hence the parser can be null.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

The `String parsedSentence = parser.parse(sentence);` statement is still reachable (at least potentially, according to the compiler) because you haven't explicitly placed it in an `else` block; Java will just process the first `if` block and then move on to the rest of the method.

You could fix that problem by formatting like this...

```
if(sentence==null){
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("sentence can't be null");
} else {
    String parsedSentence = parser.parse(sentence);
}
```

... but what you should do instead is use a try block:

```
public ParsedSentence parse(String sentence) throws NullPointerException {
    try {
        String parsedSentence = parser.parse(sentence);
        return new ParsedSentence(parsedSentence);
    }
    return null;
}
```

Since that means this method could return a null too (or throw an exception), you'll have to make sure you deal with that in a similar way inside whatever method you're calling this one from

Comment: did you see my editing? my question is if parser is null, an earlier exception would have been thrown in the getParser() method and the program will terminate immediately. Right?

Comment: Still though, the getParser() method is perfectly capable of returning null, which means parser could very easily be null at runtime

Comment: So in your try-catch block, it deals with two types of possible nulls at the same time: sentence is null or parser is null?

Comment: The 1st snippet where you added the else is no different from what OP had. If it enters the if block it will throw an exception, it will not continue with the rest of the function. The 2nd snippet, does that even compile? Try without catch?

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't really "deal with them" at all since it doesn't have a catch statement. You'd still have to make sure you wrap your `parse(xyz)` call inside a full try-catch block at some point or the exception won't get handled

Comment: What can I do if I want to the program terminates immediately in the getParser() method? It doesn't make sense to enter the parse method, if the getParser() fails.

Comment: @NickL I mean we know in practice that the statement is unreachable, but the compiler doesn't necessarily know that. As far as I know you don't have to catch an exception either as long as you declare you're throwing one so that another method can catch it

Comment: I am pretty sure that doesn`t compile.. why would you even want to write a try without catch, resources or finally?

Comment: @martin if you want the program to shut down completely you can always use `System.exit(0)`

Comment: The compiler would for sure know that, but the NPE does not come from `sentence` being null, but `parser` being null. The whole if statement has nothing to do with it.

Comment: @NickL you still have to catch it somewhere, but that's what I mean when I say he'd need to wrap the call to `parse` in a full try-catch block

Comment: But if you look at my getParser() method, I have to use a try catch block to handle. System.exit(0) doesn't seem to fit here.

Comment: @NickL you're probably right, but in any case it's a bad way to structure your code

Comment: @martin you'd put `System.exit(0)` in your catch block

Comment: You should not catch NPE's, they are programming errors. You should check whether it is null, and properly deal with it where you can.

Comment: You could check in `parse` whether `parser` is null, and throw an `IllegalStateException` if this is the case. If you would throw an exception in the static initializer you will run into a `NoClassDefFound` error or something, which is not very nice.

Comment: NickL, a second thought, why doesn't directly throw an NullPointerException?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to execute a parse() when sentence is null then what you should do is:

```
if (sentence != null) {
return new ParsedSetence(parser.parse("sentence"))
}
```

Comment: OP flagged as Java not C#

Comment: i feel dumb... it looks pretty much the same